# jquery ui autocomplete id and close event ui parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery Ui Autocomplete 1.8.14 and I would like to do two things:

Assign an id to the autocomplete. For instance, I might have many autocompletes on page and I'd need a way to identify each. In particular, in the background autocomplete is generating something like

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 444px; left: 48px; display: block; width: 118px;">
```

What I would like is to assign and id to the `ul` tag. The reason why I want to do this is for the following reason…

There is a [close event](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-close) and one of the parameters is `ui`. In the "select" even this `ui` is populated with data that is used to create the autocomplete but for the close event, `ui` is empty. That's why I would like to have an id on the `ul` tag in my previous question. If I can get the `ui` data then I don't need to bother with setting the id although I would think that it's a desirable feature regardless.

Hope I was reasonably clear.

EDIT: Apparently, I wasn't clear enough :). Hopefully, the following will help clarify what I mean:
After an item is selected from the autocomplete, I am using the select event to populate other form elements using the "ui" parameter. That's working all fine and great.

However, now what I want to do is this, say in the autocomplete I write out an item which exists in the autocomplete. However, I don't select the item but instead tab to the next form element. What I would like to happen is to check the term entered in the autocomplete, loop through the autocomplete list. If the term entered matches one of the items in the list, I just get the data out of the "object attached" and then populate the form elements accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "ui data"? Could you elaborate on what you want to get from the `ui` please?

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks. One further question, what is the source for the autocomplete. Is it an AJAX search or a local array?

Comment: @andyb: the source of the autocomplete is an AJAX search

Comment: @andyb: Here is a cut down version of what I'd like to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/mxzuF/ and it's related to the following question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787644/accessing-attached-json-object

Comment: @andyb: In this example I'm using a local data store but in my production code I'm pulling the data using AJAX. Thought I'd clarify that just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pbjcF/) that I think does what you want. I suspect there is a better way of doing this though. I literally took the part of the question about <kbd>TAB</kbd> and bound an event to that key.</strike>

Note: I have just seen your comment on the question, so will have a look at that demo as well now. So in my demo the JSON data is in a different format, so it might need some tweaking.

Oh, I've just found an [existing extension](http://dev.nemikor.com/jquery-ui-extensions/autocomplete/autoSelect.html) that might already do what you want (from [here](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/08/extensible-autocomplete/)) Typical! :-)

**Edit** Oh I see, most of the code is already done in [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxzuF/). All you need to just use `$parentItem.data('item.autocomplete');`.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll try and see if that's what I want and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not quite what I want to do although I'm pretty sure I need that kind of functionality :). Hopefully with my jsfiddle example, what I require is clearer. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @DavidS updated my answer having looked at your example code.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! How did you know about this .data syntax? The reason I ask is because I'd rather learn by myself than asking.

Comment: Happy to help! It's part of jQuery, see [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and but has also has meaning in [HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). A lot of extensions hide things here. It's a very nice and simple way of storing `<key, value>` pairs against a DOM node.

Comment: Thank you once more! Using this code has helped simplify my code as well. :). Bonus really. But my question really is how did you know to look in the data object? I suppose with hindsight it makes sense...

Comment: Oh I see... 2 reasons really: the `_renderItem` function in the [jQuery UI source](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.js) and the screenshot you posted on the other question :-)